# I need to write Regx for text field validation, which start with either 'iqn.yyyy-mm.com.' or 'eqn.'

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to write Regx for text field validation, which start with either 'iqn.yyyy-mm.com.' or 'eqn.'
After this any number of character or numeric value is allowed
Here 'yyyy-mm' is year and month.

Comment: That's a requirement, not a question. Read [ask] and do some research before posting.

Comment: Please do mention what you [**tried**](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

If we are just validating the year and month and before and after chars are OK, then this expression might work:

```
.+\.[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}\..+
```

If we wish to add more constraints, we can surely do so by modifying these two `.+` in the start and end of string. We can also add start and end chars, if necessary.

```js
const regex = /.+\.[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}\..+/gm;
const str = `iqn.2019-10.com
eqn.2019-10.com
eqn.209-10.com`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eKro0O/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eKro0O/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean is "either 'iqn.yyyy-mm.com.' or 'eqn.'":

```
pattern = new RegExp('/^(iqn\.\d{4}-\d{2}\.com\.)|(eqn\.)$/');

var str = 'iqn.2019-05.com.';
pattern.test(str); // -> true

var str = 'eqn';
pattern.test(str); // -> true

var str = 'anything else';
pattern.test(str); // -> false
```

or, if you mean is "either 'iqn.yyyy-mm.com.' or 'eqn.yyyy-mm.com.'":

```
pattern = new RegExp('/^[ie]qn\.\d{4}-\d{2}\.com\.$/');

var str = 'iqn.2019-05.com.';
pattern.test(str); // -> true

var str = 'eqn.2019-05.com.';
pattern.test(str); // -> true

var str = 'anything else';
pattern.test(str); // -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
^[ie]qn\.(?:\d{4}-\d{2}\.\w{2,6})?\.?.+$
```

Regex101 Link here : [Link Here](https://regex101.com/r/emcDDX/1)